# How to find the state index and do the process of splicing the data

Tags: reactjs

I have module where I need to remove the table row when I click the trash icon. Now I create remove each row function and pass the index clicked. Doing the splice is working well however the problem is always the last array is removed not the clicked row is removed. I hope this more cleared.

**Here is in my console log, as you can see the index clicked is 2 however the deleted index is 4.**

[image: logs]

IntialData:

```
const list_bank =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_banks.data);
    const list_remarks =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_remarks.data);
    const list_bank_accounts =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_bank_accounts.data);
    const list_customer_payor =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_customer_payor.data);

    const initialData = [
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        }
    ] 
    
    const [stateInitialData, setStateInitialData] = useState(initialData);

    useEffect(() => {
        setStateInitialData(initialData);
    }, []);
```

Button:

```
<th style={{backgroundColor:'#FFFF',borderTopColor:'#FFFF'}} onClick={() => RemoveEachRow(index)}><DeleteOutlined/></th>
```

Table:

```
    <table className="table  table-fixed table-hover table-striped bankaccount " style={{ width: "100%", zIndex: "-9" }}>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CUSTOMER / PAYOR</th>
            <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>BANK</th>
            <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>BRANCH</th>
            <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CHECK NO</th>
            <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CHECK DATE</th>
            <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>AMOUNT</th>
            <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>REMARKS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {
        stateInitialData.map((data, index) => {
            
            return (
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <span>
                            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option selected>Select Customer</option>
                                {
                                    data.customer_payor.map((customer_payor_data) => {
                                        return (
                                            <>
                                                <option value={customer_payor_data.id}>{customer_payor_data.type == '1' ? 
                                                customer_payor_data.company_name  + ' / ' +  customer_payor_data.contact_person : (customer_payor_data.payer)}</option>
                                            </>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span>
                            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option selected>Select Bank</option>
                                {
                                    data.bank.map((bank_data) => {
                                        return (
                                            <>
                                                <option value={bank_data.id}>{bank_data.bank_name}</option>
                                            </>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span>
                            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option selected>Select Branch</option>
                                {
                                    data.bank_branch.map((bank_branch_data) => {
                                        return (
                                            <>
                                                <option value={bank_branch_data.branch}>{bank_branch_data.branch}</option>
                                            </>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span>
                            <input className='form-control' type='text'/>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span>
                            <input type="date" className="form-control"/>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span>
                            <input className='form-control' type='text'/>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span>
                            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option selected>Select Remarks</option>
                            {
                                data.remarks.map((remarks_data) => {
                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            <option value={remarks_data.check_remark}>{remarks_data.check_remark}</option>
                                        </>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </select>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th style={{backgroundColor:'#FFFF',borderTopColor:'#FFFF'}} onClick={() => RemoveEachRow(index)}><DeleteOutlined/></th>
                </tr>
            )

            
        })  
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Remove Function:

```
const RemoveEachRow = (indexClicked) => {

        console.log(indexClicked,"index clicked")

        let InitialData = [...stateInitialData];

        console.log(InitialData, "Initial State");

        let newData = InitialData.findIndex((item,index) => index !== indexClicked);
        
        console.log(newData, "new Data");
        
        InitialData.splice(newData, 1);

        setStateInitialData(InitialData);

    }
```

```js
const {useState} = React;

const ReceiveCheck = () => {

    let data = [
        {
            customer_payor: "1",
            bank: "1",
            bank_branch: "1",
            check_no: "1",
            check_date: "1",
            amount: "1",
            remarks: "1",
        },
        {
            customer_payor: "2",
            bank: "2",
            bank_branch: "2",
            check_no: "2",
            check_date: "2",
            amount: "2",
            remarks: "2",
        },
        {
            customer_payor: "3",
            bank: "3",
            bank_branch: "3",
            check_no: "3",
            check_date: "3",
            amount: "3",
            remarks: "3",
        },
        {
            customer_payor: "4",
            bank: "4",
            bank_branch: "4",
            check_no: "4",
            check_date: "4",
            amount: "4",
            remarks: "4",
        },
        {
            customer_payor: "5",
            bank: "5",
            bank_branch: "5",
            check_no: "5",
            check_date: "5",
            amount: "5",
            remarks: "5",
        }
    ] 


    // let data = [
    //     {
    //       label: "0",
    //       label2: "test"
    //     },
    //     { label: "1", label2: "test1" },
    //     { label: "2", label2: "test2" },
    //     { label: "3", label2: "test3" },
    //     { label: "4", label2: "test4" },
    //     { label: "5", label2: "test5" },
    //     { label: "6", label2: "test6" }
    // ];

    const [list, setList] = useState(data);

    const RemoveEachRow = (index) => {

        console.log("-----", index);

        setList(list.filter((item,indexList) => indexList !== index));
        
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <table >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CUSTOMER / PAYOR</th>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>BANK</th>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>BRANCH</th>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CHECK NO</th>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CHECK DATE</th>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>AMOUNT</th>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>REMARKS</th>
                <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {list.map((entry, index) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>{index}</td>
                  <td>{entry.customer_payor}</td>
                  <td>{entry.bank}</td>
                  <td>{entry.bank_branch}</td>
                  <td>{entry.check_no}</td>
                  <td>{entry.check_date}</td>
                  <td>{entry.amount}</td>
                  <td>{entry.remarks}</td>
                  <td
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: "#FFFF",
                      borderTopColor: "#FFFF"
                    }}
                    onClick={() => RemoveEachRow(index)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <ReceiveCheck />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: why are you searching with !== for indexes?

Comment: also why `th` inside `tbody` and not `td`?

Comment: @Apostolos does it conflict if that I used?

Comment: no but it is weird TBH :)

Comment: sorry for that @Apostolos this is weired i tried const newData = initialData.filter((item,index) => index !== 1); always the last index is removed.

Comment: check this simple codesandbox. `https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-paper-41hvc` if this helps you. it uses `filter`

Comment: @Apostolos hi. i found out where the problem is but I don't know why the newList is not replacing the old one. const [stateInitialData, setStateInitialData] = useState(initialData); the setStateInitialData is not working well.

Comment: you need to provide us with a sample project like i did in codesandbox or wherever you like in order to test it better and help you better.

Comment: sure. for a while will do that.

Comment: @Apostolos I add snippet on my thread please see on it thanks

Comment: your code works fine. i replaced 1s with more descriptive numbers. now you can see that filter works fine

Comment: it not works on my side.

Comment: @Apostolos if you try to delete it. always on the last is remove

Comment: I found out the problem, is this new? the total table header must be match the number of table data? let say if  you declared 8 times of <th> then  <td> must be 8 times?

Answer (score 3):

You just change `findIndex` to `filter`:

```
const newData = InitialData.filter((item,index) => index !== indexClicked);
setStateInitialData(newData);
```

Comment: any description why I need to use filter rather than findIndex?

Comment: Because you just use only one function `filter` instead of `findIndex` and `splice`

Comment: sorry your suggestion is not working well. only the last array removed

Comment: please post a codesanbdbox. Viet's code seems ok

Comment: I add more details.

Comment: @Viet I add snippet on my thread please see on it

Answer (score 2):

1. [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is for finding the index when you have complex checks and do not know the actual index.
2. [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies the array in place.  (The original array is modified)

But since you already have the index, why not use splice/slice directly with it? What [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will do is return a new array after your modification.

```
        let newData = InitialData.slice(indexClicked,1);
        
        console.log(newData, "new Data");
        
        setStateInitialData(newData);
```

Comment: Tushar. doing the slice is removing all the array.

Comment: You want to remove the element at indexClicked position from InitialData right? You are saying newData is empty?

Comment: yes your correct. the indexclicked must be removed not the last array.

Comment: Can you share  a small repro in codeSandbox or something similar?

Comment: i will add more details I think I need to add my table row.

Comment: Hi Tushar I add snippet please see on it

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. I am assuming you are getting correct index value:

```
const RemoveEachRow = (indexClicked) => {

        console.log(indexClicked,"index clicked")

        let initialData = [...stateInitialData];

        console.log(InitialData, "Initial State");

        let newData = initialData.filter((item,index) => index !== indexClicked);
        
        console.log(newData, "new Data");
       
        setStateInitialData(newData);

    }
```

Basically filter out all the array which is not equal to index and set that value in state

Comment: any description why I need to use filter rather than findIndex?

Comment: sorry this is not working. the last array is removed not the clicked

Comment: I add more details